# Why is it That My <A href="foo"> Works, But My <Link to="foo"> Doesn't?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have what I think is a standard routing setup:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route component={SubPage} exact path="/sub/path" />
    <Route component={FrontPage} exact path="/" />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I manually navigate to `/sub/path` everything works fine.  When I click a standard link (`<a href="/sub/path">`) it also works just fine.

However, when I use a `<Link to="/sub/path">` (and click on it) I am navigated to the URL of `/sub/path` ... but the component for it is not rendered.  Instead of seeing the subpage I continue seeing the front page, even though the URL changes.

If I refresh the page, or go backward and forward, the router kicks in, but for some reason using `Link` is making it not render the route.  Can anyone suggest why?

Comment: Where do you render your Links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Routes and Links must be Wrapped by the same instance of `BrowserRouter`. Make sure both of them share the same instance of BrowserRouter in their ancestory.

Also do not have multiple instance of `BrowserRouter` or in general any Router in your App

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <>
   <Link to="/sub/path">SubPage</Link>
   <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Switch>
    <Route component={SubPage} exact path="/sub/path" />
    <Route component={FrontPage} exact path="/" />
  </Switch>
  </>
</BrowserRouter>
```